# SQL Server: Select X amount of character from value

Tags: sql-server, nvarchar

I have a database with a nvarchar(50) column. All rows have >25 chars always in this column.

I would like to return only the first 10 characters from column WITHOUT getting all the data from SQL and getting the 10. Is it possible to ask SQL to return on the 1st 10 from a specific column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for [LEFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx)?
`SELECT LEFT(col_name,10) FROM your_table`

Comment: What happens if `col_name` is less than 10 chars long?